# How do I download the graphics.py for Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to download the `graphics.py` module off this site here http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ and I want to save the link in my `Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages` which is where the README says to install third party packages....

I save it there with the name `graphics.py` and then try `import graphics` in my python shell but it gives me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics'

I need this module to start the next chapter in my book, how can I import it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a conda expert but try this: when a conda environment is activated, do `pip freeze` to see what packages you have available and pick one, doesn't matter which one. Then run `python` repl and import it, for example:

```
$ python
>> import six
```

Then you can inspect that imported module to see where it's located:

```
>> six.__file__
```

This should give you a location of your `site-packages. Something like:`/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py`Put your`graphics.py` in that directory. You should be able to import it after that.